# How to ban Hostname using a Wildcard with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can i ban requests form pingdomtools?

Their hostnames looks like that:

```
s464.pingdom.com
```

So how can i ban all hostnames ending with

```
pingdom.com
```

?

Comment: I don't think Apache resolve hostnames to use there. It would delay the HTTP requests quite a bit. Maybe you should check for IP masks instead.

Comment: Hm okay thats bad then. Actually i can't check the ip's cause pindom own about 500 different servers with completly different ip's. But i guess i found out a solution. If it works i post the solution later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a rewrite rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*tumblr\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

http://davidwalsh.name/block-domain

- Note: This blocks based on referer, which can be spoofed or left out entirely.

**Update:** On servers that do reverse dns you can try:

```
deny from .pingdom.com
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html#allow

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} somesite\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since it's not easy to ban the hostname i just banned the User agent:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Pingdom.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://go.away/
```

Works fine.